# facebook and css, how to place a like comment dialog on top of a video?

Tags: css, facebook

i have a youtube video and a like button on top of it. The problem occurs when i click the like button and the 'leave comment' dialog opens. it goes underneath the video.

```
<div>    
<div class="like_like">
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=211607088882&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.xxx.com/tpain.php" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="240" height="40" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
</div>
</div>
<div class="insidde_video">
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CNmCOTBsAwQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

any ideas?

### thanks

the solution is to add `?wmode=opaque` on the youtube iframe src. ex: `<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-oQFSfuRy24?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

thanks all

Comment: I would put the like button next to the video. Even once you do get the z-index fixed, it will look bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining some properties for the `<param>` element of the video embed:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

That should make the video obey the z-index stacking of elements on the page. However, you have been warned that using this method may cause massive slowdowns.

There is also a [javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704485/how-to-add-wmode-transparent-for-every-flash-object-ebmed-tag/4281735#4281735) to this, although looking more cumbersome, doesn't require hardcoding on your behalf.

Comment: the solution is to add ?wmode=opaque on the youtube iframe src