# How to place Facebook send dialog box above other content?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I just can't figure this out - I've tried positioning, floating and z-index, but without any success...

My problem can be seen here: http://procycling.fi/2/uutiset/40-kilpapyoraily/594-paavo-paajanen-aloitti-liegen-ympaeriajon-vatsataudissa

When you press the send button, you can see that the opening dialog box goes behind the main content area. In a way it's very similar to this case: [facebook and css, how to place a like comment dialog on top of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513903/facebook-and-css-how-to-place-a-like-comment-dialog-on-top-of-a-video), but that's about flash.

Hopefully a solution could be found!

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s no z-index issue. You assigned *overflow: hidden* to .component-content .rt-article-icons but it should be *overflow: visible*