# <object> tag 'WindowlessVideo' parameter doesn't work on some systems

Tags: javascript, media-player, media, windows-media-player

I am having a media player with object tag and there is a dropdown immediatedly above that in y web page. The issue was that the dropdown contents was not overlapping the video player. Instead the dropdown menu used to be hidden by the video player.

Here is the reference to the earlier question:

[Dropdown contents not overlapping video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495825/dropdown-contents-not-overlapping-video-player)

I was able to solve this by using a param tag given below:

```
<param name="WindowlessVideo" value="-1">
```

This works fine in my system on IE 9 . However the same thing doesn't work on another machine which has IE 9 too. There, it plays only audio and there is no video. Just a blank screen !!

Is it an issue with some plugin for windows media player that is required? I haven't done anything extra on my system.

Comment: it is a problem with the machine and *** windows at all... the specs say Version
Windows Media Player for Windows XP or later.
DLL
Wmp.dll required

Comment: Isn't that DLL available with the default installation of windows media player? Does it have to do anything with the 'WindowlessVideo' parameter?

Comment: what i wanted to express is that most people with ie9 seem to say it works and the code refference says its supported, so i would rather check some more machines to get a better empress of what is going on, the theory that sth. is wrong with a "used" windows setup is more possible than anything else on the web

Comment: I found it working on 5 systems and not working in 3 systems. With all having IE 9 or above. It is even working for one of the IE 8 system i checked with with the dropdown appearing properly above the media player. But in others, video won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

the promblem is maybe the Others system's media players Codecs , that they are not uptodate :|
the problem is not from your code ,it maybe is from the Media Player.

Comment: What specific codec? Shouldn't it come with the default installation of media player? I haven't done anything extra on the systems in which the video is working fine.

Comment: if u have updated your window Or anyOther os they will automatically do fine , but if it is not up to date , u have to do it for the system